# File sharing between android and opencv

Tags: android, communication, native

I am trying to invoke opencv library from my android code.

I previously stored my haar xml under the /data/data/org.siprop.opencv/files/ directory and passed this file path (i.e. /data/data/org.siprop.opencv/files/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml) to the opencv library. This xml was successfully read by the opencv code.

But I noticed that these xml files were not packaged in the .apk file which meant I would have a problem when distributing the same.

I hence tried storing these haar xmls in the assets/files folder. Now the files were included in the .apk file but i could not locate this in the emulator via the DDMS file explorer. So not sure what file path can I pass back to the opencv library.

Can you please let me know where am i going wrong?

Comment: Hi, any pointers to this issue

Comment: did you find the way? then please post here